# Convert irregular array of arrays into an array

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array of values and an array of arrays of indices that looks like this (the real arrays are way bigger):

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([np.array([0,1,2]),np.array([0,4]),np.array([1,3,5])])

B = np.array([5,10,3,7,8,4])

for a in A:

    np.max(B[a])
```

The endgame would be to remove the loop to save some computing time, but the main issue is that the irregularities in size in the A array keeps me from doing a simple C=B[A]. Is there a way out?

edit: My issue is apparently not clear enough, so I'll try to clarify. In the end, I want this array: [10,8,10] meaning an array giving the max of B[0],B[1],B[2], the max of B[0],B[4] and the max of B[1],B[3], B[5].

Comment: what do you expect as result when you do `B[A]`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Your loop is incomplete, since you don't hang onto the results, not even print them.  But I assume you want 3 values, one for each subarray of `A`.  If `A` was a 2d array, you could use `max` with an axis parameter.  For most practical purposes, your `ragged` `A` is a list of arrays.  Python level iteration of the elements of `A` is the only option.

Answer (score 0):

In order for this to work, you need to concatenate your arrays into a single array.

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([np.array([0,1,2]),np.array([0,4]),np.array([1,3,5])])

B = np.array([5,10,3,7,8,4])

print(B[np.concatenate(A)].max())
```

This gives the same max result without the loop.

Notice that initializing `A` as an `np.array` of `np.array`s is deprecated.

Comment: I think the OP wants 3 values, one for each subarray of `A`.  Your answer gives just one max,

Comment: Yes that's exactly right, I want the max for each row